# How to load configuration file of which name is not related to the exe file name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

It seems `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()` is related to the current application's name.

I want to load the configuration file of which name is not related to the exe file name.

For example, application file name is "MyApp.exe" and custom configuration file name is "OtherApp.exe.config".

In following methods, Which method should I use to load OtherApp.exe.config from MyApp.exe?

```
OpenExeConfiguration()
OpenMachineConfiguration()
OpenMappedExeConfiguration()
OpenMappedMachineConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are properties specific to every appdomain.

You can make use of one of them.

The below sample code shows how to load the confilgfile with different name.
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "someothername.exe.config");

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added code like following but still doesn't work correctly. AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", configfile);
m_config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configfile);

Comment: SetData method is working for me.  It works only if you make this statement run before loading any configuration.  For ex. in WinForms application, this method should be first line in Main method otherwise the application would be bound with the default config file.

Comment: I moved SetData before loading configuration file. Thanks!

Comment: @Don - If this resolved the issue, then can you please mark this as answer.